# How can I use Jeditable Function?

Tags: asp.net, jeditable

How can I use this Jeditable function to reflect changes in the text. 
In asp.net web form I want to commit edited text to the DIV.

```
 <div class="editable_textarea">
        Headline Dear
    </div>



$('.editable').editable(function(value, settings) { 
         console.log(this);
         console.log(value);
         console.log(settings);
         return(value);
      }, { 
         type    : 'textarea',
         submit  : 'OK',
     });
```

Do I need to make one more aspx page to collect the value then need to reflect on first page. Or I can do it directly without making another save.aspx page with the above function, if possible then how can I do that please tell me a little on it.

Comment: Is there any body to help me out with this, so that i can save changes to the text. i am in dire need.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in this program? Do you just want the DIV to show the edited text without sending the value to the server?

Comment: i don't want to make another save.aspx page where it returns the edited text, i want to use this function to make it directly on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you posted is really what you are after, perhaps taking away the `console.log()` calls:

```
$('#editable').editable(function(value, settings) {
    return value;
}, {
    submit: "OK",
    type: 'textarea'
});
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/2wBEW/1/.

Comment: Somehow the function is not called for me... have you had similar issues?

Comment: you may want to create a new question and put more description about it, so you can get more help from the community. If not, you can leave comment here, and I might be able to help you out.